# Django DateTimeField default with timezone

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am trying to use the DateTimeField in a postgresql model. I have set time zones to be true in the settings and the model field is:

```
pickupTime = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now())
```

However, when I run python manage.py migrate there is an error:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: cannot cast type time without time zone to timestamp with time zone
```

I have tried different variations for the DateTimeField default value like:

```
models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
```

but the error is still the same. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
pickupTime = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
```

It should work.

Comment: Great it works! The thing is, By passing datetime.now without the parentheses, you are passing the actual function, which will be called each time a record is added, on the other hand, If you pass it datetime.now(), then you are just evaluating the function and passing it the return value.

Comment: It's not working with django 3.2 when applying migrations: django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ['“” value has an invalid format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ] format.']